# Table pagination not going to a different page when selected

Tags: php, html, mysqli, pagination

I added pagination to a table a I created a while back and I have not ever been able to get it to work correctly since.

The table limit works, but that's it. If I select "First, Last or the page number" it just reloads the page, but the new page does not display.

If I set the page limit to a low number like 5 and select 'Last Page', when the page loads it shows =1 like it doesn't know there are other pages.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
$per_page=20;

    if(isset($_POST["page"])) {

    $page = $_POST["page"];
    }
    else {
        $page = 1;
    }

//Page will start from 0 and multiply per page
    $start_from = ($page-1)*$per_page;

//Selecting the data from the table but with limit
    $query = "SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
?>

<table class="tableproduct">
    <tr>
        <th class="thproduct">Order ID</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Customer Name</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Product</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Total Price</th>
        <th class="thproduct"></th>
        <th class="thproduct"></th>
    </tr>
  <?php
      if( $result ){    
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) :
   ?>
 <form method="POST" action="orderhistory.php">
    <tr>
        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['order_id']; ?> </td>
        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['customer_name']; ?> </td> 
        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?> </td>
        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['total_price']; ?> </td>
        <td class="tdproduct"><a href='editorderhistory.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>EDIT</a></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
        <td class="tdproduct"><input name="delete" type="submit" value="DELETE "/></td>
    </tr>
</form>
<?php   
    endwhile; 
    }
?>
                    </table>
<?php
 //Count the total records
if ($result != false) {
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($total_records == 0) {
        echo 'No results founds.';
    }
}

//Using ceil function to divide the total records on per page
$total_pages = ceil($total_records /$per_page);
?>
<span class="spandarkblue">
<?php
//Going to first page
echo "<center><a href='orderhistory.php?page=1'>".'First Page'."</a>   ";

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {

echo "<a href='orderhistory.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>   ";
};
// Going to last page
echo "<a href='orderhistory.php?page=$total_pages'>".'Last Page'."</a></center>";
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: One of your variables is probably not being set correctly for some reason. Debugging their values should be a good start, even using die()

Comment: Is all the paginations links (like first, pageno, last) points to page no 1 or they point to different page number in url ??

Comment: @SameerK they all point to page number 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found below issues in you code.

1) You are trying to get page value from URL using POST, where as you need to GET method to fetch values from URl. Using POST is returning null value, so `$page` value is always set to 1

So use `$_GET["page"]` instead of `$_POST["page"]`

2) You are preparing pagination by considering row count of the query which you are executing. But as you have added `limits` , your `$total_records` is always equals to $per_page value or less, resulting in only one page number.

Use the following code for generate pazination

```
$query1 = "SELECT count(*) as totalRecords FROM orders";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
if ($result1) {
      $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
      $total_records = $row1['totalRecords'];
     if ($total_records == 0) {
         echo 'No results founds.';
      }
}
```

Instead of below code

```
if ($result != false) {
   $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   if ($total_records == 0) {
      echo 'No results founds.';
   }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: When I did part two of your answer, it now goes to a different page with last page, but it still isn't showing additional pages. It now only shows "First" "Last". It also echos the "No Results Found"... I have it set to 5 results per page and I have over 20 records.

Comment: While tying , i made mistake in query where i was not considering the count of rows. I have edited my answer , Please check.

Comment: Got it! I appreciate it. Do you know if there is any way to make this work with Ajax, so I don't constantly have to reload the page?

Comment: Thanks and yes certainly you can use ajax. As i cant share the full code here, pointing you to some references http://onlinewebapplication.com/pagination-jquery-php-ajax-mysql/  and http://www.thesoftwareguy.in/ajax-pagination-with-php-and-mysql/.

Comment: Excuse me, but using `count(*)` this will only return a number... @Paul, do you have any data from your query with this?

Comment: Fine @Paul, the main thing is that somehow you had what you need! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch **all** the data to know the total of your records, then you show only the desired data whithin a `for()` loop, so remove `LIMIT $start, $per_page` from your query, in this node you will always have 20 or less results

In your `while()` save the data in arrays like this:

```
$index = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ordID[$index] = $row["order_id"];
    // The rest of your data...
    $index++; // Increment the index
}
```

Then you chan show only the desired data:

```
for($i = (($page-1)*$perPage); $i < min(($page*$perPage), $total); $i++) {
    echo $orderID[$i];
    // And so on...
}
```

The `min()` function returns the lowest value between two vars, in this way in the last page, if you have 17 products instead of 20 you will not have errors.